# Property of outer measure in regard to null sets

Tags: measure-theory

If $E\subset X$ is a null set, then $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(A \cup E) = \mu^*(A\setminus E), \forall A \subset X$.

I felt tempted to assume that since A and E are disjoint, I could use the additive property, namely  $\mu^*(A \cup E)= \mu^*(A)+\mu^*(E)= \mu^*(A)$. Am I doing it right?

Edit: clarify that $\mu^*$ is the outer measure.

Comment: $A$ and $E$ doesn't need to be disjoint

Comment: Then $\mu^*(A \setminus E)= \mu^*(A)-\mu^*(E)= \mu^*(A)$?

Comment: what you says hold, however it doesn't imply that $E\subset A$

Comment: Never implied $E\subset A$. So other than that, have I sufficiently proved the problem?

Comment: you hadn't prove something. To prove something you need to justify every identity or step you did invoking known theorems or definitions